# Unable to hide a line of text until a certain date

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic

I am trying to hide a line of text until a certain date, and then have it hidden when it reaches another date.

Can you help?

I am using a .asp (classic) page.

This works fine, it will hide the text after the 12/02/2016

```
<% If Date() >= CDate("12/02/2016")   Then %>
<h3 style="margin:4px 0 3px 0;">TEXT</h3>
<% End If %>
```

But for example, I want to hide it until 11/02/2016, show it on 12/02/2016, and then hide it again on the 13/02/2016

```
<% If Date() >= CDate("12/02/2016")  and Date() >= ("13/05/2016") Then %>
<h3 style="margin:4px 0 3px 0;">TEXT</h3>
<% End If %>
```

If anyone can help and can suggest any resources on this that would be great!

Comment: `If Date() >= #12-Feb-2016# And Date() < #14-Feb-2016# Then`

Comment: If you only want to show it on one day, wouldn't it be simpler to check for `If DateDiff("d",Date,CDate("12/02/2016")) = 0 Then`? (After checking to make sure your server is interpreting the bass-ackwards date correctly. [I'm sorry, I know mm/dd/yyyy is nonsensical, but dd/mm/yyyy is even worse.])

Answer (score 0):

Your test

```
<% If Date() >= CDate("12/02/2016") and Date() >= ("13/05/2016") Then %>
```

effectively tests if the current date is greater or equal to 13/05/2016.
What you probably want is

```
<% If Date() >= CDate("12/02/2016") and Date() < ("13/05/2016") Then %>
```

or more readable

```
<% If CDate("12/02/2016") <= Date() and Date() < ("13/05/2016") Then %>
```